# Inject SessionFactory from Spring XML-Config into Java-Config

Tags: java, spring

For some reason i have my spring beans config as java config and also some other beans are defined in xml.
Now i want to inject the sessionfactory bean defined in xml config into a bean in java config.
Unfortunately sessionfactory is null and i get a NullPointerException.
What's wrong? I'm using Spring 3.2.5. Also @Inject or @Autowired instead of @Resource doesn't work.

Here are the relevant parts...

Java Config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource({ "classpath:beans-sessionfactory.xml" })
public class MyJavaConfig {

   // defined in 'beans-sessionfactory.xml'
   @Resource
   //@Inject => also NPE
   //@Autowired => also NPE
   private AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory;

   @Bean
   public MyDao getMyDao() {
      final MyDao dao = new MyDao();
      // Why is sessionFactory null?
      dao.setSessionFactory(this.sessionFactory.getObject());
      return dao;
   }

   // MyAppConfig extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
   @Bean
   public MyAppConfig myAppConfig() {...}
...
```

XML-Config:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
...
</bean
```

Unit-Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyJavaConfig.class })
public class MyBeanWiringTest {
   // test fails with NPE
}
```

The almost complete beans-sessionfactory.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

  <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" lazy-init="true">...</bean>

  <bean id="myProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">...</bean>

  <bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">...</bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
      <list>
        <value>MyEntity</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Are you sure `beans-sessionfactory.xml` contains the `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` bean definition you are showing us?

Comment: Sure, it works also for my xml configured application. Only for another application using Java Config and xml config it doesn't work. There is a NPE as explained in question.

Comment: Also wiring of other beans from xml doesn't work (NPE).

Comment: Can you show us an image of your project or your classpath? I'd also like to see the full content of `beans-sessionfactory.xml`.

Comment: I've added the xml to the question.

Comment: Are you using maven? Do you have an empty context file called `beans-sessionfactory.xml` in `src/test/resources`?

Comment: Don't inject the `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`, inject the `SessionFactory` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

> Bean method MyJavaConfig.myAppConfig is non-static and returns an
>   object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. 
>   This will result in a failure to process annotations such as
>   @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring
>   @Configuration class.  Add the 'static' modifier to this method to
>   avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean Javadoc for complete
>   details

So after declaring myAppConfig static it works.

```
@Bean
public static MyAppConfig myAppConfig() {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` is a `FactoryBean<SessionFactory>` which means that it creates a `SessionFactory`. You can inject the result instead of the factory.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource({ "classpath:beans-sessionfactory.xml" })
public class MyJavaConfig {

   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   @Bean
   public MyDao getMyDao() {
      final MyDao dao = new MyDao();
      // Why is sessionFactory null?
      dao.setSessionFactory(this.sessionFactory);
      return dao;
   }
```

If you really want the `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` you will have to resort to some naming trickery. You have to inject a bean with the name '&sessionFactory' notice the `&` this is the marker to indicate to spring that you want to `FactoryBean` instead of the result of the  `FactoryBean`.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("&sessionFactory")
private AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory;
```